# how to save two plots simultaneously in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, numerical-methods

Hiii...

I havebeen trying to plot two curves simultaneously in a single plot to compare them. ie, by the command:

plot "1.txt" w l, "2.txt" w l

now I want to save it, but the usual command for saving is:

set out "1.txt"

but in this case how can I save them together in a same plot?

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and prefix lines of code with 4 spaces. Or select multiple lines of code with the mouse and click the `{}` formatting button. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

For saving a plot as a file on your disk, you need to setup two things: a `terminal` and an `output`. Suppose you have configured your plot interactively in a command-line gnuplot session, this is an example:

```
set terminal png
set output "myplot.png"

replot

unset output
```

where `replot` does what its command name suggests, it repeats the last `plot` command - and if that last plot command showed both curves as you wanted it, they will identically show up in the output file. For info on supported terminal types on your system, read `help terminal`.